# Lotus Domino - DAOS not reducing file size?

Tags: ibm-domino

I have implemented DAOS on a Lotus Domino Server (8.5.3 FP2) as follows:

Lotus Domino Server Document:

- Store file attachments in DAOS:  Enabled
- Minimum size of object before Domino will store in DAOS: 64000 bytes
- DAOS base path:  E:\DAOS
- Defer object deletion for:   30 days

Transaction logging is running, and the specific test database has the following advanced properties set:

- Domino Attachment and Object Service (ticked)
- Use LZ1 compression for atachments
- Compress Database Design
- Compress Data

I have restarted the server. When I run a **compact -c**, it compacts the database, but does not reduce the size.  I have checked the DB in Windows Explorer (60Gb) and the size is the same pre and post.  I have checked the directory (E:\DAOS) and it is 35Gb in size.

When I run the command 'Tell DAOSMgr Status tmp\test.nsf', I get the following response.  From looking up on the net, I believe ticket count = 0 means that the db is not really DAOS'ed?

```
Admin Process: Searching Administration Requests database
DAOSMGR: Status tmptest.nsf started
DAOS database status:

Database: E:\Lotus\Domino\Data\tmp\test.nsf
Database state = Synchronized
Last resynchronized: 03/09/2012 02:49:13 PM
Ticket count: 0
DAOSMGR: Status tmp\test.nsf completed
```

I have run fixup on the database.  When I have tried to run the DAOS estimator it has always crashed.  This was a problem with larger databases on earlier versions of domino, but not anymore.

Can anyone tell me why the size has not reduced?  Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - looks like the problem was with the database.  I ran a fixup on the db which deleted a corrupt document - this was a test db so will now find out what the corrupt document was.

Now, when I run 'Tell DAOSMgr Status tmp\test.nsf', I get the following response:

```
DAOSMGR: Status tmp\test.nsf started
DAOS database status:
Database: E:\Lotus\Domino\Data\tmp\test.nsf
Database state = Synchronized
Last resynchronized: 13/09/2012 07:24:33 PM
Ticket count: 106165
DAOSMGR: Status tmp\test.nsf completed
```

Ticket count no longer 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have DAOS slightly mixed up. DAOS removes the attachments out of documents and stores them on the server, so if one emails is sent with a large attachment it is not stored in every database, just one file in DAOS.

Here are some links:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21449358 this is to reduce the number of nlo files.

Also someone on IBM support ask the same question, I would recommend reading it [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/0/8cc4599555f5adf9852577e5004acc02?OpenDocument)

Comment: Thanks - I have looked into it further and have worked out the problem, see below.  Thanks for the links, there was some confusion there.  I am not looking to reduce the size of the NLO files, but the size of the DB.  Looks like there was a db problem which is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There are some important points when you implement DAOS (in my eyes). Some are also mentioned [here](http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/categories/notes-domino/158-sntt-enabling-daos-and-some-considerations.html?showall=1&limitstart=)

1.) You should keep your Backup software in mind, not every supports DAOS. If the software didn´t support DAOS you still CAN restore the mailfile but must then restore each *.nlo file per hand to the DAOS folder. You can find more infos here:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/daos-backup-and-restore

So the most company's enable DAOS on there primary server (from a cluster) and on there 2nd server which act as failover they run the backup (without DAOS enabled).

2.) I would enable DAOS also on the mail.box as mentioned here:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/daos-best-practices#Mailbox

3.) Keep in mind that the NLO files are encrypted on default. This might be a problem for the restore on your side.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/daos-best-practices#Encryption
http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/notesini-reference/bycategory/14-server_configuration/2245-daosencryptnlo.html

4.) You should exclude the NLO via antivirus:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/daos-best-practices#Antivirus